# Decoding all HTML Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-entities

I'm looking for some function that will decode a good amount of HTML entities.

Reason is I am working on some code to take HTML content and turning it into plain text, the issue that I have is a lot of entities do *not* get converted using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`.

Some examples of entities I'm concerned about are &nbsp;, &amp;, &copy;.

This is for *.net 3.5*.

Comment: I switched to .Net 3.5 and used `Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;, &amp;, &copy;"));` and it worked fine for me. I can't figure out why you'd be having trouble. Do you have a weird string encoding or something?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Then maybe you will need the **HttpUtility**.HtmlDecode?.
It should work, you just need to add a reference to System.Web.
At least this was the way in .Net Framework < 4.

For example the following code:

```
MessageBox.Show(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&amp;&copy;"));
```

Worked and the output was as expected (ampersand and copyright symbol). 
Are you sure the problem is within HtmlDecode and not something else?

**UPDATE:** Another class capable of doing the job, WebUtility (again HtmlDecode method) came in the newer versions of .Net. However, there seem to be some problems with it. See the [HttpUtility vs. WebUtility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode) question.

Comment: You are correct, it was how I was using the result, if I put it into an asp:label it would convert the copywrite character into &#169;.

Comment: I see. That is pretty useful to know :).

Comment: If it's using js ```encodeURI()``` use ```HttpUtility.UrlDecode()```

Answer (score 23):

Use `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` included in .Net 4

For example, if I run in a console app:

```
  Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;, &amp;, &copy;"));
```

I get `, &, c`

Comment: I probably should have said this is for .net 3.5.  I +1'ed you though.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: What is the difference between WebUtility and HttpUtility's `HtmlDecode` method?

Comment: There's an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352981/webutility-htmldecode-vs-httputilty-htmldecode

In short - WebUtility came with WinRT, it's newer while the HttpUtility is the old one (used all over the place so I expect it to stay).
Also I think WebUtility is in System.dll (System.Net), which makes it a bit more accessible for WinApps (you don't have to depend on System.Web) if I remember correctly.