# Convert HTML entity in XML to its equivalent Unicode in C#

Tags: c#, xml, html-entities

I have several HTML entities in an XML returned by a web service as `XmlDocument` type. I need to replace them with their equivalent Unicode characters, before applying XSLT transformation.

XML Snippet

```
<ics>
 <record>
  <metadata>
    <meta name="Abstract" content="In the series of compounds observed after effect of &amp;#947;-quanta"/>
  </metadata>
 </record>
</ics>
```

I'm using C# with .Net 4.0. I tried using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` on the `OuterXml` property of the above XmlDocument, but it doesn't convert the HTML entities to Unicode.

How can this be achieved?

**EDIT:**

I see that applying HtmlDecode once gets `&amp;#947;` to `&#947;`. If I apply it once more, I get the required Unicode.

Any better ways to do it?

Comment: In here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348879/decoding-all-html-entities it says it should work. What do you mean with "it doesn't convert [...] to Unicode" ?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`WebUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx) in .NET 4.0

Also, `&amp;#947;` decodes to `&#947;` verbatim, **not** the Unicode character `γ`. Main problem is that your "HTML" is incorrect. You'll have to do it twice to get the gamma character.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using both WebUtility.HtmlDecode and HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the OuterXml, but the resulting string has the &#947; instead of its Unicode equivalent.