# getting the translated language using google translator in winform apps

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to translate a string from "English to Bangla" in my WinForms app.
I tried this code:

```cs
string input = "i eat rice";
string languagePair = "en|bn";

string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
MessageBox.Show(result.Trim());
```

But what I got is:
`&#2438 &#2478 &#2495 &#2477 &#2494 &#2468 &#2454 &#2494 &#2439`
But if I put it in Google's search box then it shows my translated language into the search box.
How can I get the translated language to show in my WinForm? 
N.B: I don't want to use google translator API.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you are getting, `&#...`, is the HTML entity encoding of each UTF-16 character.  You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` or `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` to get the actual unicode string.

```
result = HttpUtitlityDecode(result.Trim());
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

See [Decoding all HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348879/decoding-all-html-entities) for more details.