# How to unescape special character when populating dropdownlist from a sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have the following C# code which populates a dropdownlist:

```
public void PopulateInsurance()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetInfo", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstr"]));
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader ddles = default(SqlDataReader);
    ddles = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    ddlI.Items.Clear();
    ddlI.DataSource = ddles;
    ddlI.DataValueField = "id";
    ddlI.DataTextField = "title";
    ddlI.DataBind();
    //set the default value for the drop down
    ListItem Item = new ListItem();
    Item.Text = "Any";
    Item.Value = "0";
    ddlInsurance.Items.Insert(0, Item);

    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
}
```

One of the row in the SQL table has the following values:

```
id     title
9      Worker&#39;
```

The dropdownlist shows the title as displayed above (`&#39;` -> which a single apostrophe`'`)

How can I modify the code so it takes the `&#39;` or any other special character and unescapes it to show the character, in this example `'`.

Comment: You shouldn't have those characters in your database at all.  Your escaping is broken elsewhere.

Comment: See [Decoding all HTML Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348879/decoding-all-html-entities) and figure out how you can get that to work with the SqlDataReader.

Comment: We had a similar issue (someone's last name had an apostrophe). When we stored the data in the database, we escaped it then with a single quote. ex: O''Connor.

Answer (score 1):

The system.Uri class contains a UnescapeDataString method.  Will that solve your problem?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe. But what I want to unescape isn't an Uri per say but a column value in a SQL table...

Comment: You'll need to modify your code to add the items manually without using data binding.  The fact that the value you want to Unescape isn't a uri shouldn't matter