# Encode URL querystring from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I am trying to encode searches that are sent as querystrings (`Response.Redirect("/Find/" + TextBoxSearch.Text);`). There is a row in the database with names including `/` and `+`, and when that enters the URL things stop working properly. I have tried encoding like this:

```
String encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TextBoxSearch.Text);
Response.Redirect("/Find/" + encode);
```

But can' get it to work, what am I missing? Pretend the search value is `ex/ex 18+`. How could I get this to work as a querystring?

Don't know if this is important but here is how I get the querysting in my Find-page:

```
IList<string> segments = Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments();
string val = "";
for (int i = 0; i < segments.Count; i++)
  {
     val = segments[i];
  }

search = val;
```

I can't even encode spaces properly.
I try:

```
String encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(TextBoxSearch.Text);
Response.Redirect("/Find/" + encoded);
```

But this does not turn spaces in the querystring in to %20. It does transform "/" though.

EDIT: At this point I would be happy to just turn this url `localhost/Find/here are spaces` in to `localhost/Find/here+are+spaces`

EDIT: I have been searching and trying solutions for over 5 hours now. 
Can anyone just tell me this:

- If I redirect like this `Response.Redirect("/Find/" + search);`
- And I make a search like this `Social media`
- I then Get the queryString as the code above using segments.
- Now I want to display info about `Social media` from my database
- but at the same time I want the url to say `Find/Social+media`

PS: Do I need to encode every url-string? or just where I use signs and spaces.

Comment: Use [Entity](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) to do so, slashes are exclusive for url, so you might using slash entity equivalent `&#46;` and + entity equivalent `&#43;`. Your Url will look like this : `http://www.mywebsite.com/Find/ex&#46ex&nbsp;18&#43`.

Comment: But how would set this in code? how does my app know to turn these values in to Entities? I have places where you can press the value from the database instead of searching for it etc.

Comment: Then when you want to get back the url, to know how to turn those into "normal" characters, use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(my_url_string)` (see more in [this Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348879/decoding-all-html-entities)).

Comment: None of this is necessary, in fact treating URLs like HTML is a bad idea. `UrlEncode` isn't broken, it converts spaces to `+` which *are* valid in query strings. Use UrlPathEncode if spaces are expected in the address

Answer (score 0):

Instead of [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) use [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode(v=vs.110).aspx). From the documentation of UrlEncode:

> You can encode a URL using with the UrlEncode method or the
>   UrlPathEncode method. However, the methods return different results.
>   The UrlEncode method converts each space character to a plus character
>   **(+)**. The UrlPathEncode method converts each space character into the
>   string **"%20"**, which represents a space in hexadecimal notation. Use
>   the UrlPathEncode method when you encode the path portion of a URL in
>   order to guarantee a consistent decoded URL, regardless of which
>   platform or browser performs the decoding.

The `+` character *does* represent a space in query strings but not in the address part.