# Convert XMl string to HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a XML string that contains these characters

```
&amp;lt&#x3b;br &#x2f;&amp;gt&#x3b;&#xa;&amp;lt&#x3b;br &#x2f;&amp;gt&#x3b;&#xa;
```

How do I convert this into real HTML code like

```
<br /><br />
```

using asp.net C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decoding all HTML Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348879/decoding-all-html-entities)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Html.Decode` in order to do so:

```
@Html.Decode("&amp;lt&#x3b;br &#x2f;&amp;gt&#x3b;&#xa;&amp;lt&#x3b;br &#x2f;&amp;gt&#x3b;&#xa;")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize built in .NET utilites to decode the HTML characters such as ampersand (&).

See: [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) and [WebUtility.HtmlDecode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.htmldecode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_WebUtility_HtmlDecode_System_String_) (.NET 4.0+)

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the encoding rules for XML differ from those of HTML (there are only 5 characters that need encoding in XML).  This function is useful for encoding XML:

```
System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(unencodedString);
```

I use this for decoding encoded XML (note that the ampersand is last in the list):

```
 public static string XmlDecode(string encodedString)
  {
      var workingBuffer = new StringBuilder(encodedString);
      workingBuffer.Replace("&lt;", "<")
          .Replace("&gt;", ">")
          .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
          .Replace("&apos;", "'")
          .Replace("&amp;", "&");
      return workingBuffer.ToString();
  }
```

Now, if the source is encoded HTML, then the other answers are correct.